# Is there any way to easily convert/render 2d canvas elements to 3d?

Tags: canvas, 3d, 2d, render

I have a small problem. Im trying to convert 2d canvas objects as group do 3d and than rotate them. I have them in 2d as I want. I have found some tutorials but none of them helped me. Can it be converted like context.render3D() or something similar? Im stuck. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I'm almost entirely sure the answer is *no.*

Do you mean rendering a 2D image with a perspective? Or painting a cube with some 2D image and rotating the cube? Or something else entirely?

If you need true 3D you should look into the WebGL canvas and one of the many good libraries that make WebGL accessible.

[ThreeJS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is probably a good starting point for you. Have a look at their [examples page](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) and see if any of these are remotely like what you want to do, then use that example as a guide.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved that with scale(1, 0.65); and shade under it. So now it looks like 3D. But I was intrested if it is possible and I think I am not the only one. :) Thanks again for so fast reply.